# How to map texture coordinates perfectly to a tile by using a tilemap?

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I am unable to map a tile **perfectly** on a quad, by perfect i mean that it will render only the pixels from a specific tile in the texture image, and nothing more.

**Edit: (updated code a bit)**

I have now made example working code:

```
/*
Image of the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drb5U.png
edit: the bug seems to change on different gfx cards, but still visible one way or another!
*/
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Glu32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

HDC hDC = NULL;
HGLRC hRC = NULL;
HWND hWnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

bool active = 1;
int window_width = 640;
int window_height = 480;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_ACTIVATE: {
            active = !HIWORD(wParam);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE: {
            exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_SIZE: {
            window_width = LOWORD(lParam);
            window_height = HIWORD(lParam);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

BOOL create_window(int width, int height){
    GLuint PixelFormat;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    DWORD dwExStyle,dwStyle;
    RECT WindowRect;
    WindowRect.left = (long)0;
    WindowRect.right = (long)width;
    WindowRect.top = (long)0;
    WindowRect.bottom = (long)height;
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("test");
    if(!RegisterClass(&wc)) return FALSE;
    dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    ShowCursor(TRUE);
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);
    if(!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,TEXT("test"),TEXT("test"),dwStyle|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_CLIPCHILDREN,0,0,width,height,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL))) return FALSE;
    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),1,PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,PFD_TYPE_RGBA,(BYTE)32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,PFD_MAIN_PLANE,0,0,0,0};
    if(!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd))) return FALSE;
    if(!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd))) return FALSE;
    if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd)) return FALSE;
    if(!(hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC))) return FALSE;
    if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC)) return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    SetFocus(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}



int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    if(!create_window(window_width,window_height)){
        return 1;
    }
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

    // create red/yellow checkers pattern with slightly randomized tile pixels:
    int img_w = 256;
    int img_h = 256;
    int tilesize = 16;
    unsigned int *data = (unsigned int *)malloc(img_w*img_h*4);
    unsigned int colors[] = {0xFF3333, 0xFFFF33};
    for(int y = 0; y < img_h; y+=tilesize){
        for(int x = 0; x < img_w; x+=tilesize){
            unsigned int i = ((x/tilesize)+((y/tilesize)%2))%2;
            for(int yy = 0; yy < tilesize; yy++){
                for(int xx = 0; xx < tilesize; xx++){
                    int r = ((colors[i]>>0)&255)-(rand()%30);
                    int g = ((colors[i]>>8)&255)-(rand()%30);
                    int b = ((colors[i]>>16)&255)-(rand()%30);
                    if(r < 0) r = 0;
                    if(g < 0) g = 0;
                    if(b < 0) b = 0;
                    data[(y+yy)*img_w+(x+xx)] = (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // take one tile somewhere from middle and make texcoords for it:
    int x = 2*tilesize;
    int y = 4*tilesize;
    float tx1 = (float)x/img_w;
    float ty1 = (float)y/img_h;
    float tx2 = (float)(x+tilesize)/img_w;
    float ty2 = (float)(y+tilesize)/img_h;

    unsigned int texid = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texid);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img_w, img_h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    free(data);

    BOOL done = 0;
    static MSG msg;

    float zpos = 600.0f;

    while(!done){
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT){
                done = TRUE;
            }else{
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }else if(active){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLdouble)window_width/(GLdouble)window_height, 0.1f, 5000.0f);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();

            glRotatef(0, 1,0,0);
            glRotatef(0, 0,1,0);
            glRotatef(0, 0,0,1);
            glTranslatef(0, 0, -zpos);
            zpos /= 1.02f;
            if(zpos < 0.2f) zpos = 0.2f;

            // draw something...
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
            glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(tx1,ty1); glVertex2f(-10,-10);
                glTexCoord2f(tx2,ty1); glVertex2f(0,-10);
                glTexCoord2f(tx2,ty2); glVertex2f(0,0);
                glTexCoord2f(tx1,ty2); glVertex2f(-10,0);
            glEnd();
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(tx1,ty1); glVertex2f(0,0);
                glTexCoord2f(tx2,ty1); glVertex2f(10,0);
                glTexCoord2f(tx2,ty2); glVertex2f(10,10);
                glTexCoord2f(tx1,ty2); glVertex2f(0,10);
            glEnd();

            Sleep(16); // dont run too fast or you break your legs!

            SwapBuffers(hDC);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And a code with multiple tiles (to see same bug when less zoom):

```
/*
Image of the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drb5U.png
edit: the bug seems to change on different gfx cards, but still visible one way or another!
*/
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Glu32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

HDC hDC = NULL;
HGLRC hRC = NULL;
HWND hWnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

bool active = 1;
int window_width = 1024;
int window_height = 768;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_ACTIVATE: {
            active = !HIWORD(wParam);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE: {
            exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_SIZE: {
            window_width = LOWORD(lParam);
            window_height = HIWORD(lParam);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

BOOL create_window(int width, int height){
    GLuint PixelFormat;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    DWORD dwExStyle,dwStyle;
    RECT WindowRect;
    WindowRect.left = (long)0;
    WindowRect.right = (long)width;
    WindowRect.top = (long)0;
    WindowRect.bottom = (long)height;
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("test");
    if(!RegisterClass(&wc)) return FALSE;
    dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    ShowCursor(TRUE);
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);
    if(!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,TEXT("test"),TEXT("test"),dwStyle|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_CLIPCHILDREN,0,0,width,height,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL))) return FALSE;
    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),1,PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,PFD_TYPE_RGBA,(BYTE)32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,PFD_MAIN_PLANE,0,0,0,0};
    if(!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd))) return FALSE;
    if(!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd))) return FALSE;
    if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd)) return FALSE;
    if(!(hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC))) return FALSE;
    if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC)) return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    SetFocus(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}



int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    if(!create_window(window_width,window_height)){
        return 1;
    }
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

    // create red/yellow checkers pattern with slightly randomized tile pixels:
    int img_w = 256;
    int img_h = 256;
    int tilesize = 16;
    unsigned int *data = (unsigned int *)malloc(img_w*img_h*4);
    unsigned int colors[] = {0xFF3333, 0xFFFF33};
    for(int y = 0; y < img_h; y+=tilesize){
        for(int x = 0; x < img_w; x+=tilesize){
            unsigned int i = ((x/tilesize)+((y/tilesize)%2))%2;
            for(int yy = 0; yy < tilesize; yy++){
                for(int xx = 0; xx < tilesize; xx++){
                    int r = ((colors[i]>>0)&255)-(rand()%30);
                    int g = ((colors[i]>>8)&255)-(rand()%30);
                    int b = ((colors[i]>>16)&255)-(rand()%30);
                    if(r < 0) r = 0;
                    if(g < 0) g = 0;
                    if(b < 0) b = 0;
                    data[(y+yy)*img_w+(x+xx)] = (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned int texid = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texid);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img_w, img_h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    free(data);

    BOOL done = 0;
    static MSG msg;

    float zpos = 600.0f;

    while(!done){
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT){
                done = TRUE;
            }else{
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }else if(active){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLdouble)window_width/(GLdouble)window_height, 0.05f, 5000.0f);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();

            glRotatef(0, 1,0,0);
            glRotatef(0, 0,1,0);
            glRotatef(0, 0,0,1);
            glTranslatef(0, 0, -zpos);
            zpos /= 1.02f;
            if(zpos < 0.1f) zpos = 0.1f;

            // draw map from randomly picked tiles:
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
            glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
            static GLuint my_list = 0;
            static bool list_made = 0;
            if(!list_made){
                int map_w = 100;
                int map_h = 100;
                int tiles_x = img_w/tilesize;
                int tiles_y = img_h/tilesize;
                my_list = glGenLists(1);
                glNewList(my_list, GL_COMPILE);
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                for(int y = -map_h; y < map_h; y++){
                    for(int x = -map_w; x < map_w; x++){
                        int xt = (rand()%tiles_x)*tilesize;
                        int yt = (rand()%tiles_y)*tilesize;
                        float tx1 = (float)xt/img_w;
                        float ty1 = (float)yt/img_h;
                        float tx2 = (float)(xt+tilesize)/img_w;
                        float ty2 = (float)(yt+tilesize)/img_h;
                        float x1 = (float)x;
                        float y1 = (float)y;
                        float x2 = (float)(x+1);
                        float y2 = (float)(y+1);
                        glTexCoord2f(tx1,ty1); glVertex2f(x1,y1);
                        glTexCoord2f(tx2,ty1); glVertex2f(x2,y1);
                        glTexCoord2f(tx2,ty2); glVertex2f(x2,y2);
                        glTexCoord2f(tx1,ty2); glVertex2f(x1,y2);
                    }
                }
                glEnd();
                glEndList();
                list_made = 1;
            }
            if(list_made){
                glCallList(my_list);
            }


            Sleep(16); // dont run too fast or you break your legs!

            SwapBuffers(hDC);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is also what this bug is about:

[image]

In the image above i have created a checkers pattern of red/yellow tiles.

I can fix this by reducing 0.0001f from the tx2 and ty2 texcoords, but it is not acceptable since the tiles wont be right sizes anymore, and it still doesn't fix the problem completely.

**Note:** the error appears only in one corner (top right in this case).

What I'm looking for is to render a tile and be 100% sure that nothing else will be rendered from that texture except the tile i want.

- Is it really not possible, is this normal in opengl?
- Could it be fixed by a shader perhaps?

Only way i know how to fix this is to pad the tiles edges with same color as the tile edges are. Or create 256 separate images of 16x16 size, which isn't acceptable.

**Edit:**
I tested the code with my other computer: it has the same bug too, but different: it only shows the problem at TOP of the quad, and only at the top! and its also ONLY 1 pixel thick for whole time, (and visible from the beginning, while on my other computer its not). in my other computer the error is in top and right side, so i believe its a gfx card/driver problem... I don't have any more computers to test it on, and I believe the error is visible one way or another in any computer. if someone can test the code, and you don't see the error, please tell your gfx card model and maybe driver version.

Comment: You may be running into [this famous pixel-to-texel alignment issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx). Not sure if it affects OpenGL, but it could be related depending on your mapping. Otherwise, I'd double-check your units and make sure no rounding is going on; I see a lot of lossy division in your example.

Comment: The pixel alignment issue is independent of filter, even the fanciest gaussian 3D ones suffer. If you're seeing a small edge of "bad" pixels, you probably have off-by-1 or rounding errors.

Comment: With no scale given in the image, it looks exactly like an off-by-1 or filter/texture mode error, as previously stated and given in the answer. The downvote and vote to close are because you refuse to even consider any possible solutions, despite likely suggestions.

Comment: Can you post something other than your division code? Like your rendering code or something more representative of the totality of the issue? Because your problem could be here or it could be elsewhere. It shouldn't be hard to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for this.

Comment: @Rookie: Actually, that was me. I downvoted due to your rudeness, stand-offish behavior in the comment thread, and frequent use of CAPSLOCK in talking to people who are *trying* to help you. He gave you the most common solution to the problem you were having, because you *never said* that you had already tried it. You were the one who did not state what you had tried, so it's not Peachy's fault that he suggested something you'd already done. Go calm down somewhere and come back in an hour with an SSCCE.

Comment: @Rookie: Half of the purpose of the SSCCE is that the person who's having the problem has to write it. This means that they have to also verify that it happens with the SSCCE, because if it doesn't, then they know to compare it with their current code to find their mistake. 60+% of errors get fixed this way. Let me put it this way: there is nothing *theoretically* wrong with what you're doing. This means that there's a bug in your code. Where that bug is cannot be ascertained without *having your code*. Hence the SSCCE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7770/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-rookie)

Comment: If I remember correctly dividing float by int is not a good idea with opengl - you can get funny results in many places. Divide by 256.0f. Also, regardless of texture filter you use, you MUST adjust primitive coordinates by 0.5f (half-pixel) when you want to render them onto 2D scene. If you won't do that, anything that must be rendered with pixel precision (say, circle made out of points, detailed 2D sprite) will look ugly. Since there are many places where you could screw up in this case, you need to post source code (SDL/GLUT-based) that shows the problem. Otherwise - ask fortune-teller.

Comment: @SigTerm, i have tried with float too, the error doesnt disappear, and btw, doesnt it divide by float automatically when i cast the first value to float? also, i cant adjust half a pixel: i want to see the tiles completely! that is the problem here, i am asking if this could be fixed, because i could easily write tiling engine without opengl by drawing pixel by pixel, and i just want to be able to do that in opengl as well. half a pixel certainly fixes this problem, but its not the answer to my problem, i would rather pad my tiles than cut half a pixel off: then tiles would look weird/wrong.

Comment: The example code has a few issues and a few inconsistencies, that may (or may not) be contributing to or exacerbating the issue: you're specifically turning on alpha in the blending and texture, but not using it or initializing it, which will set it to 0. You still have mixed int, uint and float throughout your division. You're using some `wgl*` functions and some not, with no apparent pattern (that shouldn't even work), and the buffer is never properly swapped/flipped. You're including `glew` and linking against `GLU` and using neither.

Comment: You're generating mipmaps and asking for a non-nearest sampling method, which alone can cause most of this problem (depending on how the hardware chooses to blur lower mip levels). Your min filter also specifically asks for mipmaps, though that should be less an issue. Nothing in the sample even suggests division, rounding or texel position is *not* in play, so some evidence of that is needed. Attempting to compile it now, will edit shortly.

Comment: @peachykeen, i dont know about the inconsistencies, the code is compileable at least and it works just fine. i couldnt remove any headers or libs out of it or i would get compiler errors. mipmaps have nothing to do with this... when i zoom in, its not even thinking about mipmaps, so it shouldnt matter when zooming in, its not blurring anything, and i tested with GL_NEAREST instead of GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST and no difference. i dont know what you mean by division/rounding... can you instead post an answer and copypaste the lines of codes where the problems are?

Comment: @peachykeen, or lets go to the chat? also the only reason im using glew/glu is because i need to use gluPerspective(), i dont know non-glu replacement for it...

Comment: I noticed that, but you're linking against `GLU` and including `GLEW`, which seems odd. I doubt that's the root of your problem, but you probably want to use one or both, instead of half and half. I've got to run in to work, but I'll try to jump in the chat in a half hour or so.

Comment: @Rookie: " doesnt it divide by float automatically" 255 is an int, not a float. While C++ does convert types, it is recommended to specify types explicitly, otherwise you'll get incorrect results in places where compiler decided to convert float to int first. In OpenGL it means you can lose fractional part."i cant adjust half a pixel" Well, like it or not, you have to. When drawing onscreen 2D primitives, it makes sense to add 0.5f to 2d coordinates - to take pixel/texel alignment into account. Also, there is a difference between "texel" and "pixel" and you don't seem to be aware of it.

Comment: Your problem does not occur on winxp/gtx 460, even with zpos == 0.02f and znear = 0.01f; It is not visible even with "magnify"/9x zoom. Since you're rendering 3d primtiives, not 2d, my previous advice to adjust by half of a pixel does not apply. However, keep in mind that floating points used in OpenGL calculations have limited precision, which is 16 decimal digits for doubles and 8 for floats. Also, consider using SDL (or something similar) for future projects -this will make code less messy.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on the new example provided. Note that the previously stated information is still correct, because sub-pixel precision is a real issue (which is why I'm leaving it there). However, that's *not* the cause of the random lines that show up well before reaching those sub-pixel limits in the new case.

The lines at lower zoom levels are caused by simple imprecision in the texture coordinate interpolation. What you want to pass is a half-open range: [0/w, 16/w). But if the interpolator produces exactly 16/w, then it will fetch from the 16th texel.

The typical solution for this is to apply a small bias to the texture coordinate:

```
float tx2 = ((float)(xt+tilesize)/img_w) - (1.0f / 8192.0f);
float ty2 = ((float)(yt+tilesize)/img_h) - (1.0f / 8192.0f);
```

This will also get rid of the sub-pixel issue, because you're applying a bias to the texture coordinate.

It won't be "pixel perfect", but if it was pixel-perfect the *first* time, you wouldn't have seen the issue. Pixel-perfection is always relative when dealing with scaling and textures.

It will be pixel-perfect within the bias specified. Which is 1 out of 8192. Given your case of a 256x256, image, that's pixel-perfect within 1/32nd of a pixel. You would have to magnify a tile by 32x before you would be even *one pixel* off.

If you can tell the difference without taking it into an image editing or processing application, or otherwise by counting pixels, I'd be very surprised).

If you go for bigger images, you may want a smaller bias. Note that the effectiveness of the bias itself is *absolute*; the smaller the bias, the greater the chance of seeing the problem again. For example, with a bias of 1/32768, my Radeon HD-3300 shows the issue. So 8192 is pretty close to the largest the denominator can get.

Note that padding the top-left of each tile would also work. Personally, I'd stick with the bias unless you have so many tiles that the bias is affecting the rendering of the image.

Note that shaders provide ways to resolve this issue without modifying the texture coordinate, by simply passing the texture coordinates as pixel-coordinate, and clamping them to just before the edge. This works with any texture resolution. Array textures would work by putting each tile in its own entry in the array.

So those are your options.

---

Note: I'm running an AMD HD-3300 card.

What appears to be happening when extremely close to the object is that the texture fetch unit seems to be running out of sub-pixel bits of precision. I can tell because if I change the threshold at which the zoom stops to the point where it is just on the cusp of happening, I can expand the window's size and then it appears. So it's the apparent screen size that's inducing the effect.

I was able to rule out texture coordinate interpolation precision issues by increasing the size of the texture to 4096. That changed nothing about when the issue appeared. So it must be in the texture fetch unit hardware itself, not the texture coordinate interpolation unit. That is, the interpolated texture coordinate is fine; it's when the hardware does the math to get the texel to fetch from that things go wrong.

After some experimentation, it looks like the issue appears when the texel is being mapped to a size of about 64-90 screen pixels. So it seems you get about 6 sub-pixel bits of precision before things get messy.

Comment: So it's a combination of texel mapping, rounding, sampling, and pretty much *everything else* that came up in the comments? :p

Comment: @peachykeen: No. It's a combination of nothing. It is, if my conclusion is correct, an issue with the sub-pixel precision in the texel fetch units. The comments said *nothing* about that. The texture coordinate used to fetch is fine; it's the fetch *itself* that's the problem. This is **not** the typical "problems of getting pixel-perfect texturing" issue. This is a completely different issue.

Comment: @Nicol, "Try to avoid zooming in that close on pixels" - the zooming doesnt make the problem! i can see the problem even if i zoom out: when i move my camera, i see at different locations some of my quads showing the errors and some of them not. If you are right about the only top/right edges padding, then this will definitely save some texture space for me, glad to hear.

Comment: @Nicol, "This is not the typical 'problems of getting pixel-perfect texturing' issue. This is a completely different issue." THANK you for saying that, finally!

Comment: @Rookie: "i can see the problem even if i zoom out" The problem I saw did not appear until you zoomed in. Can you make an example that shows the problem without the zooming? Because this description of the problem strongly suggests that it *is* the typical 'problems of getting pixel-perfect texturing' stuff, and has nothing to do with sub-pixel bits of precision.

Comment: @Nicol, of course it didnt when my camera never moved in x/y axes, but when i zoom out in my tiling engine, i see those lines, that was the very reason i notice this bug. (actually i have noticed it years ago but just now i wanted some answers for it since i felt like the padding is very stupid fix for it). i will make example of it too then... :D

Comment: @Nicol, Here you go: http://pastebin.com/8nGTsBX5 - its a bit harder to notice, but you'll see the flashing of lines! also i realised that it doesnt actually need camera movement... just zoom in/out. i also now remember that originally i zoomed in so much just to show you that its not a pixel being drawn half way or etc, but only like 1/500'th part of a pixel is missing.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: "an issue with the sub-pixel precision in the texel fetch units" and it is most likely amd-specific. I didn't see any issue on my GeForce GTX: http://pastebin.com/4ia3XXWi

Comment: @SigTerm, why on earth did you add even more dependencies in your code? just wondering, because the stuff you added doesnt really add up anything important, just harder to compile. i made my code as less dependencies i could for a reason. I think you are right about the ATI cards though, its probably not visible on nvidia.

Comment: "You would have to magnify a tile by 32x before you would be even one pixel off." not necessarily, all i need is to draw 32 tiles (or something like that), and i would see one of them 15x16 in size instead of 16x16... that is the problem, i really, really want to have pixel precise rendering... i dont like the bias option, because the value i need to decrement is just absurdly random value, and i cant have enough trust to that TBH, so i would prefer padding since it will ensure everything and theres no need to use any high tech shaders/array textures etc.

Comment: @Rookie: "all i need is to draw 32 tiles (or something like that), and i would see one of them 15x16 in size instead of 16x16" The size of the quads you draw is *not* affected; you're only biasing the texture coordinate. So you wouldn't see one as 15x16. Try it at 1x1 scaling; you will see *no difference*. Oh, and shaders were "high tech" 9 years ago. Nowadays, they're standard equipment. Fixed function is obsolete; that's why the ARB yanked it out of the spec 3 years ago.

Comment: @Rookie: "even more dependencies in your code" your code is not portable and requires windows platform. Mine is (more or less) portable and requires libsdl+libfreetype, which are available on multiple platforms. Being locked into single platform (especially into windows os) isn't much fun, and using windows api actually adds more dependencies to your project than using cross-platform framework that allows you to quickly convert your entire app to different os.

Comment: @Rookie: "high tech shaders/array" Doom 3 requires shaders, and runs on GeForce 3. GeForce 3 was released in 2001. 10 years ago. Right now it is not uncommon to have pixel shaders in smartphone and a credit-card sized device can run quake 3. 10 years ago this was science fiction.

Comment: Nicol: did you test it? im pretty sure it will happen, because one of the pixels arent 100% in size, so if you draw the tiles in a row enough, one of their textures becomes eventually 15x16 instead of 16x16, so even if the quads are 1:1 size, their texture wont: you will see one line of pixels 2px thick. @SigTerm: fair enough, but you added a font library/timers/keyboard which were useless: the program was fixed at 60fps max, and it didnt really need esc to quit, nor space to zoom, nor std::max() to replace my if() :P

Comment: @Rookie: "didnt really" Look, in this case you should really test your code and fix your problems yourself - without asking other people for help. You uploaded the code, so I'll tear it apart and modify in any way I want. There are many ways your code fragment could be improved (for a start you could ditch malloc from your C++ program).

Comment: @SigTerm, malloc works fine, i dont see a reason replace something which isnt broken.

Comment: @Rookie: std::vector also works fine. Anyway, my policy is not to interfere when somebody wants to shoot himself in the foot with rocket launcher. The code needs cleanup. If you don't want to do cleanup, this is not my problem.

Comment: @SigTerm, i use std::vector when i need to: for dynamic arrays. IMO makes the code more readable, kinda like using `const` keyword for variables, so you know its not gonna change (in size).

Comment: @Rookie: whatever. As I said - if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, it is your decision.

Comment: @SigTerm, you must understand that the code i made was deliberately made as small as possible with as less dependencies as possible. i didnt even try to be pro, i tried to be SIMPLE.

Comment: @Rookie: You must understand that it is perfectly normal when other people have different opinion. I don't need to understand anything. It is your code and your decision. Also it isn't about "being a pro".

Comment: This is all fascinating, but please **take it elsewhere!** I don't want to see these messages in my inbox!

Answer (score 2):

> In the image above i have created a checkers pattern of red/yellow tiles.

Could not reproduce the problem on GTX460/WinXP, even with zpos = 0.02f.

Sounds like driver/precision/fixed function problem.

> What im looking for is to render a tile and be 100% sure that nothing else will be rendered from that texture except the tile i want.

You could store every tile in separate texture (I know it is a waste) and use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`/`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`.

Or you could add border of pixels around every tile - "expand" tile by copying pixels on edges outwards. I.e. above top edge of tile, place copy of top edge, to the left of the left edge, same to the right and bottom edges of the tile. This will waste extra texture memory (since width/height of every tile will increase by 2 pixels), but you'll never see adjacent pixel

> Could it be fixed by a shader perhaps?

Perhaps.
You could adjust texture coordinates in a fragment shader this way (non-GLSL pseudocode):

```
void adjustCoords(float &s, float &t, int tilex, int tiley){
    float sMin = (0.5f + (float)tilex)/(float)image.width,
        sMax = ((float)(tilex + tilewidth) - 0.5f)/(float)image.width,
        tMin = (0.5f + (float)tiley)/(float)image.height,
        tMax = ((float)(tiley + tileheight) - 0.5f)/(float)image.height;
    s = min(max(s, sMin), sMax);
    t = min(max(t, tMin), tMax);
}
```

before using them (texture coordinates) to actually read data from texture/sampler. However, you'll need to know tile coordinates and texture size. On other hand, nothing prevents you from encoding this data into vertex attributes/uniforms.

So, to bypass the problem, you can:

1. Use more textures (wasting performance switching them).
2. Waste texture memory.
3. Waste GPU power adjusting texture cooridnates using shader.

Decision is yours.